# Varnish and Nginx redirecting 8080 -> 80

Tags: performance, redirect, proxy, nginx, varnish

I am trying to use Varnish as a reverse caching proxy for my nginx install on Ubuntu 10.10, I have set up Varnish on port 8080 for testing and nginx is operating normally on port 80.

My nginx.conf:

```
user {user} {group};
worker_processes  16;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    client_max_body_size 4M;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    gzip        on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml$

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     off;

    keepalive_timeout  30;
    tcp_nodelay        on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

My site's .conf file:

```
server {
     listen  80;
     server_name www.mylesgray.com dev.mylesgray.com;

     access_log /var/www/mylesgray.com/logs/access.log;
     error_log /var/www/mylesgray.com/logs/error.log;

     location / {
        root /var/www/mylesgray.com/public;
        index index index.php;
        try_files $uri/ $uri index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        port_in_redirect off;
     }

     location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log        off;
        expires           30d;
        root /var/www/mylesgray.com/public;
     }

     location ~ .php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/mylesgray.com/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING     $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD   $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE     $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH   $content_length;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }

    location ~ /.ht {
        deny  all;
    }

    location ~ /.git {
        deny  all;
    }

#    include /var/www/mylesgray.com/public/nginx.conf;
}

upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

My Varnish conf:

```
backend default {
     .host = "localhost";
     .port = "80";
}

acl purge {
        "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                        error 405 "Not allowed.";
                }
                return(lookup);
        }

        if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
               unset req.http.cookie;
         }
}

sub vcl_hit {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                set obj.ttl = 0s;
                error 200 "Purged.";
        }
}

sub vcl_miss {
        if (req.request == "PURGE") {
                error 404 "Not in cache.";
        }

        if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                        unset req.http.cookie;
        }

        if (req.url ~ "^/[^?]+.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|ico|js|css|txt|gz|zip|lzma|bz2|tgz|tbz|html|htm)(\?$
                unset req.http.cookie;
                set req.url = regsub(req.url, "\?.$", "");
        }

        if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
                unset req.http.cookie;
        }
}

sub vcl_fetch {
        if (req.url ~ "^/$") {
                unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        }

        if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
                unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        }
}
```

So with all that when you goto my site on port 8080: http://www.mylesgray.com:8080 it just redirects to plain old: http://www.mylesgray.com What it should be doing instead is that (as it stands) if I access port 80 I should get nginx serving files only, and if I access 8080 I should have nginx + varnish serving files.

I'm doing this to test the performance benefits of varnish over plain nginx.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered simply using Nginx and ditching varnish all together? You will find that anything that you achieve with Varnish + Nginx can probably be done faster, cleaner and simpler with Nginx alone.

Comment: I had but then thought better of it as Varnish is not a webserver it is simple a cache so it is much quicker at serving static elements: http://danielmiessler.com/blog/optimizing-wordpress-with-nginx-varnish-w3-total-cache-amazon-s3-and-memcached

Comment: You need to be careful about following random web postings particularly when it comes to Nginx as there is a lot of poor and sometimes even unsafe stuff out there. The configuration on that page does not have any caching in Nginx whatsoever and every request goes all the way to run PHP. So yes, Nginx + Varnish will be faster compared to that but at best will only be as fast as Nginx with caching switched on which as said, will be cleaner and simpler to implement. Basically, there is no need to run Varnish with Nginx.

Comment: I agree that there is a lot of bad info out there, I don't follow them to the letter I just like the concept and make my own conf files, I saw his benchmarks (http://danielmiessler.com/blog/wordpress-optimization-results-varnishnginxapc-w3-total-cache-amazon-s3-cloudflare) and thought "well, why not?". I will run an `ab` benchmark on 2 different ports (one with nginx and one with nginx + varnish) and we'll see how it turns out. It doesn't hurt to experiment.

Comment: No it doesn't. Just make sure you switch caching on in Nginx when you run your test ... unlike his rather meaningless one.

Comment: Good call - will try that, I like the fact that Varnish caches to ram rather than to disc, I think nginx uses disk caching - maybe we will still se a difference.

Comment: Nginx caches to disc indeed but Linux will move frequently accessed stuff to RAM as required. Also, there are modules in Nginx that allow you to cache directly to RAM if you want. As said, simpler and cleaner with no need to mess with another app that only does what can already be done in Nginx. Anyway, I think there isn't any more to add so all the best whatever you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be some kind of SEO plugin that's thinking "oh a request on port 8080? That shouldn't be, I'll be kind and rewrite to port 80":

```
$ curl -I "http://www.mylesgray.com:8080/"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/0.7.65
Location: http://www.mylesgray.com/
```

You may want to normalize your host headers by stripping the port numbers:

```
set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");
```

If needed, have a look at some more examples at these [configuration examples for Varnish](https://github.com/mattiasgeniar/varnish-3.0-configuration-templates/blob/master/default.vcl)

Comment: I agree. Probably some script is doing the redirect (tested with wget -S).

Comment: Strange no scripts enabled at all - just plain WP, not in my nginx configs either... weird as hell.

Comment: Did you try the port-sanitization I placed in my comment? Did that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

A nice trick is to have both servers (nginx and varnish) on the same port, but in differents IP, say

nginx: localhost:80
varnish: 1.2.3.4:80

check this out:  http://danielmiessler.com/blog/handling-redirects-with-varnish-and-nginx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go into your WP general settings and change `yourdoma.in` to `yourdoma.in:8080`. I ran into the same problem.

Otherwise, WordPress will only *ever* listen on port 80.

Here's an [explanation by davide73 on the wp forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/running-on-port-8080#post-1456399):

> WordPress has a bug; you can't use it for a non 80 TCP port.
>
> That's because they use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] instead of 
>   $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].":".$_SERVER['HTTP_PORT']